# how to get the index for first occurence of any word from arraylist in sentence

Tags: java, android, string, search, arraylist

I want to get the index of word from the sentence. But here I don't want to check for one specific word. I have list of words and I want to get index of the first occurrence of any word from the list which available in the sentence.
I want the index to get the substring of the sentence, starting at the resulted index.

```
String sentence = "hii rahul ,nice to meet you .How are you?";
ArrayList search = new ArrayList();
search.add("are");
search.add("rahul");
search.add("meet");
for(int i=0;i<search.size();i++)
{
  if (sentence.contains(search.get(i))) {
    System.out.println("I found the keyword");
  } else {
    System.out.println("not found");
  }
```

I tried writing some code, but could not figure out how to get the index of the String `"rahul"`.

**Input:**
Sentence: `hii rahul ,nice to meet you .How are you?`
ArrayList of searched words: `["meet","are","rahul"]`

**Expected output:**
Index is 4 (as the `rahul` comes first in the sentence)

Comment: How is the index 5 for *Rahul*? Also, in your code you are using the string *'hey rahul ,how are you ?'* and in the example for input you are giving *'hii rahul ,nice to meet you .How are you?'* Do clarify that as well.

Comment: I think OP means index should be 4, the starting position of "rahul" in the String "hey rahul...". OP probably started counting at 1 instead of 0...

Comment: So basically OP wants to find the starting position in the String of the search word which occurs first.

Comment: Why do you expect an index to be the output if you don't output it? You only output if a search term was found or not.

Comment: You probably cannot get away with using contains as you want to match whole words. For example, if your sentance was "The Doctor went to the shop" and one of the searfch terms was "to", it would pick up the "to" in the word "Doctor"

Comment: @NicholasK "hey rahul ,how are you ?".indexOf("rahul") == 4

Comment: @NicholasK i edited my question. thank you!!

Comment: @deHaar I want the index to get the substring of the sentence, starting at the resulted index which i can once i get the index

Comment: @BretC yes that is also one issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to split your string into a list of words.

If you just use `contains` or `indexOf`, it may give the wrong answer. For example...

```
        String search = "Doctor Smith went gardening and then went to the cinema on Tuesday";
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList("then", "to", "went");
```

This would give the wrong answer if using `indexOf` because the character sequence 'to' appears within the word 'Doctor'.

This does a match on whole words (case sensitive)...

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class FindWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String search = "Doctor Smith went gardening then went to the cinema on Tuesday";
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList("then", "to", "went");

        int index = 0;
        int result = -1;
        String match = null;

        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(search, " ", true);

        while(result < 0 && tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
            String next = tokenizer.nextToken();

            if(words.contains(next)) {
                result = index;
                match = next;
            } else {
                index += next.length();
            }
        }

        if(match == null) {
            System.out.println("Not found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found '" + match + "' at index: " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.indexOf(String)` to determine the starting position of a substring:

```
Integer lowestIndex = null;
for(String searchWord : search) {  
    int index = sentence.indexOf(searchWord);
    // update the result if the searchWord occurs at a lower position
    if (index >= 0 && (lowestIndex == null || lowestIndex > index)) {
            lowestIndex = index;
        }
    } 
}
if (lowestIndex == null) {
    System.out.println("None of the keywords were found");
}
else {
    System.out.printf("First keyword at %s%n", lowestIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(meet|are|rahul)").matcher(searchText);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Found '%s' at position %d%n",
        m.group(), m.start());
}
```

If you want to start with a List:

```
List<String> keywords = Arrays.asList("meet","are","rahul");
String pattern = keywords.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("|", "(", ")"));
```

A regular expression search is slower, but one could add word boundaries `\\b(meet|are|rahul)` so "software" is not found. Or do a case-insensitive search.

Comment: "software" ? Where is that?

Comment: @AdriaanKoster when searching for "are" also "software" would be found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) method. But be aware that indexing starts from 0, so in your example the output will be 4.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
int firstIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for(String word : search) {
  int foundIndex = sentence.indexOf(word);
  if(foundIndex != -1 && foundIndex < firstIndex){
    firstIndex = foundIndex;
  }
}

if(firstIndex != Integer.MAX_VALUE){
  System.out.println("Found index is: " + firstIndex);
} else{
  System.out.println("None of the words were found in the sentence.");
}
```

If the word is not found `.indexOf` will return `-1`. If it is found, we save the lowest in the `firstIndex`-variable.

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##fZLdS8MwFMXf@1ec9WF06AK@7kv2oDjY9GEogojENl0z22Qk6eqQ/u01/VyF4UtKz735nXNvu6dHOt4HX0XBk4NUBnsrkNTwmCyVoqc112bq@DHVGhvKxY8DHNLPmPvQhhr7OEoeILElb2sUF7u3d9BR2QbUAjQThgmfYQ434hyKRmmMa8GtZCQSxgxOMgV5kBmoYuXLrTutEF2IWQ1bWBpVfmRZgmW98sIb1TfqOqFB4Lkl2r2gW5NLchWsLVQHFwYhV9qsRMC@renKjrJjimyWrx8vy/XzXd0cStWMj0yqAJOG2yyiAclUBC2oXQrhpfAUeuW9xtq2h16vezDH@AbDYZ8w6@XqXPA37Lm95eZOfTqtybl9cGG4Drw9acMSIlNDDnZKEwvPvS/pqOKD6wlcXPUz1ZY5WKzZf5hHKRhkCBOxancaGbP/QNjQK71bVvtxyjlyJy@KXw)